# Getting rid of nested Task type

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-tasks-api

Is it possible to get rid of nested Task generics?

For every `continueWith` statement, a new `Task` is added within the type. Every continuation is part of the type. Ideally I would return one Task which consecutively executes every single task and succeeds or fails as one.

## Example

The first operations queries the groups of a user

```
private fun getGroupsSnapshot(): Task<QuerySnapshot> {
    val userId = Auth.currentUser()!!.uid
    val query = userGroupsQuery(groupsCollection, userId)
    return query.get()
}
```

The second operation queries albums within those groups.

```
fun getAlbums(): Task<Task<List<Album>>> {
    return getGroupsSnapshot().continueWith { task ->
        val documentSnapshots = TaskUtils.getResult(task)
        val albums = mutableListOf<Album>()
        val fetchAlbumTasks = documentSnapshots.documents.map { document ->
            Log.d(TAG, document["name"].toString())
            document.reference.collection("albums").get().addOnCompleteListener { queryTask ->
                albums.addAll(toObjects(Album::class.java, queryTask))
            }
        }
        return@continueWith Tasks.whenAll(fetchAlbumTasks).continueWith allTasks@ {
            return@allTasks albums as List<Album>
        }
    }
}
```

However I would like this operation to return type `Task<List<Album>>` to keep the interface clean.

Comment: I think you might be helped with [this blog series](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html) about the task API, in particular, the [third installation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-3_29.html) that shows how to chain together Continuation objects.

Comment: Thank you! I will read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For composing multiple `Task` you should use `continueWithTask` instead of `continueWith`. It accepts a `Continuation<TResult, Task<TContinuationResult>` as a parameter, which essentially flattens the returning `Task` and avoids nesting. You should think of it as `map` vs `flatMap` operation in Monads (i.e. `List`), in this case, `continueWithTask` would be the equivalent of `flatMap` if you use `List` as the container instead of `Task` (Remember, with `flatMap` you transform every element of the `List` to a new `List`, and flatten the resulting `List`)